# Number of all possible triangles for N vertices

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Given $n$ points in space, what is the number of all possible triangles?

As I understand it, the number of all possible edges (segments) is $\frac{n * (n-1)}{2}$ [edited]

What is the next step then? The above formula can not be applied to edges, because not all edges can form triangles with any other two. Or maybe this is a wrong path to take at all.

Comment: How many vertices determine a triangle?

Comment: Your expression for the number of edges is not correct.  The plus sign should be a minus because after you picked the first end of the edge, there are $n-1$ points available for the other end.

Comment: @RossMillikan ah, of course, thanks!

Comment: @lulu is it a real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the different ways to choose $3$ objects (vertices) out of $n$ where the order doesn't matter.  This is: 
$$\binom{n}{3} = \frac{n!}{3!(n-3)!} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ is known as the binomial coefficient.

This is the same technique used to find the number of edges.
Each edge is determined by two vertices, so the total number of pairs of edges is:
$$\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Which is the answer you provided.

Note that this chooses $3$ points out of $n$, but these points may be colinear, so if you don't consider those as triangles you'll have to subtract them from the total count.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $n$ points in space and no $3$ of them are collinear (can be connected by a straight line), this problem reduces to counting the number of ways you can choose three points (the vertices) out of the $n$ points. This is $\frac {n!}{(n-3)!3!}$